# Pull Document Properties for Directory of DOC files into Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, properties, ms-word

I have a directory full of MS Word .Doc files. I need to generate a list of those files with the page count for each, e.g., "File 1- 50 words, File 2 -100 words" etc.  It seems like it'd be easiest to do this in Excel (file name in column A, page count in column B), though I'm not totally committed to that.

Frustratingly, I can view this in Windows Explorer by just adding the "Pages" field, so I know the information is there, but I can't print or otherwise work with it. I can generate a list of files to import into Excel using a command prompt Dir command, but I can't figure out a way to get that list to include page counts.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Update 2** (deleted 1 because I realized I was being an idiot):

I'm trying to execute Noodle's script from a VSB file, but getting a "Subscript out of range" error on line 6. Have not made any changes from what's posted in the reply (I did initially, but they caused different problems), and can't figure out where the error is coming from. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code dumps all shell properties for a folder that you can use Import Data in Excel to import. It's VBScript and VBScript is legal VBA, so you can optimise it for speed to VBA normal programming style or use as is.

Ag(0) is the command line parameter, ie the folder to be done. You can't use this in VBA but have to replace with the host's (excel/word) equivelent method in the app object (excel or word).

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Set Fldr=objShell.NameSpace(32)
Set Fldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=Fldr.Items
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Set DeskFldr=objShell.Namespace(16)
FName=fso.buildpath(DeskFldr.self.path, "Folder Property List.txt")


Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(FName, 8, true)



For x = 0 to 100
    t1 = t1 & Fldr.GetDetailsOf(vbnull, x) & vbtab
Next
ts.write FLDR.self.path & vbcrlf
ts.Write T1 & vbcrlf
T1=""


For Each FldrItem in FldrItems
    For x = 0 to 100
        t1 = t1 & Fldr.GetDetailsOf(FldrItem, x) & vbtab
    Next
    t1=t1 & vbcrlf
    ts.Write T1
    T1=""
Next

msgbox FName & "has a tab delimited list of all properties"
```

Note this program has different outputs depending on which version of Windows it is run on, and every version is different. My Vista does not have a page field.

Comment: I can't install the DLL, so this is the most appealing option, but I seem to be implementing it wrong.  Have edited original post to include the script I'm trying.

Comment: Just put the lines in a text file. I drag folders and drop on the file.

Comment: That worked great. Sadly, Pages is not one of the fields it outputs in 2007 either.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a [DSOfile.dll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351/en-us) which helps with this.    It lets you access properties from closed office documents.  You download it, install it by running the .exe file, and then set a reference to it in Tools/References in the VBE.

If this were to be used generally, you probably need to add a bunch of error checking to make sure inputs are valid.

Also, there may be some issues if you try to use it with 64-bit versions of Office.  I have Office 2007 32 bit running on Windows 7 Professional x64.

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'Set Reference to DSO OLE Document Properties Reader 2.1
Sub GetWordCountsFromDocs()
    Const PathName As String = "c:\users\ron\documents\"
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim FO As Folder
    Dim FIs As Files, FI As File
    Dim lWC As Long
    Dim ColWC As Collection
    Dim V()
    Dim I As Long

Set ColWC = New Collection
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FO = FSO.GetFolder(PathName)
Set FIs = FO.Files
ReDim V(1 To 2)
For Each FI In FIs
    If FI.Name Like "*.doc*" Then
        lWC = GetWordCount(PathName & FI.Name)
        V(1) = FI.Name
        V(2) = lWC
        ColWC.Add V
    End If
Next FI

ReDim V(0 To ColWC.Count, 1 To 2)
V(0, 1) = "File Name"
V(0, 2) = "Word Count"
For I = 1 To ColWC.Count
    V(I, 1) = ColWC(I)(1)
    V(I, 2) = ColWC(I)(2)
Next I

ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
Range("a1").Resize(UBound(V, 1) + 1, UBound(V, 2)) = V

End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------
Private Function GetWordCount(FilePath As String) As Long
    Dim DSO As DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties
    Dim Prop As Office.DocumentProperty
    Dim V As Variant

Set DSO = New DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties
DSO.Open sFileName:=FilePath, ReadOnly:=True
GetWordCount = CallByName(DSO.SummaryProperties, "wordcount", VbGet)
End Function
```